# Modified xfloat in latex causes runaway argument

Tags: latex

I am required to use a customized document class which modifies xfloat...

```
\input{report.cls}

% Single Space Figures, Tables, and Footnotes
% Redefine the macro used for floats (including figures and tables) so
% that single spacing is used.  (Note \def\figure{\@float{figure}set
% single spacing} doesn't work because figure has an optional argument)
\def\@xfloat#1[#2] {
  \ifhmode
    \@bsphack\@floatpenalty -\@Mii
  \else
    \@floatpenalty-\@Miii
  \fi
  \def\@captype{#1}
  \ifinner
    \@parmoderr\@floatpenalty\z@
  \else\@next\@currbox\@freelist {
    \@tempcnta\csname ftype@#1\endcsname
    \multiply\@tempcnta\@xxxii\advance\@tempcnta\sixt@@n
    \@tfor \@tempa :=#2\do {
      \if\@tempa h\advance\@tempcnta \@ne\fi
      \if\@tempa t\advance\@tempcnta \tw@\fi
      \if\@tempa b\advance\@tempcnta 4\relax\fi
      \if\@tempa p\advance\@tempcnta 8\relax\fi
    }
    \global\count\@currbox\@tempcnta
  } \@fltovf\fi
  \global\setbox\@currbox\vbox\bgroup
  \def\baselinestretch{1}\@normalsize
  \boxmaxdepth\z@

% leave captions indented, I hope
% \hsize\columnwidth
  \@parboxrestore
}
```

However, when creating a document with a float...

```
\documentclass{customclass}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
TEST
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I get the error...

> Runaway argument? tbp]TEST \end {figure}  ! Paragraph ended before
>   \@xfloat was complete.  
>                      \par  l.7

Answer (score 0):

It appears the line breaking is causing the issue. Putting the whole block in the document class on the same line fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Two things here:

1. The parameter text for `\def` is very particular, and you should be careful if you change it. For example,

   ```
   \def\abc#1[#2] {...}
   ```

   requires a trailing space in `\abc{..}[..]` .
2. `\def` (LaTeX's `\newcommand*`) doesn't allow paragraphs (empty lines or an explicit `\par`) in its definition. To allow for that you need to use `\long\def` (LaTeX's `\newcommand`).

In most cases, small changes (and additions) to macros easily made using patches instead. Such patching is provided by either of [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox), [`xpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) or [`regexpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/regexpatch).